# Unable to Drop draggable using jquery UI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

When I drag LI element mouse over on the 'Drop Header' then 
internal div should appear and where I can drop my LI element, but as soon as I reach to that internal drop area it just disapper.

Here is [***jsfidle***](http://jsfiddle.net/6jjR2/48/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#dragLi > li").draggable({helper: "clone"});
            $( ".reviewersListDv > div#droppable" ).droppable({
            over: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).find('.parallelSectContent').show();
            },
                    out: function( event, ui ) {    
                    $(this).find('.parallelSectContent').hide();
                    },
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    (ui.helper).remove(); //destroy clone
                    $(ui.draggable).remove(); //remove from list   
            $(this).find('.parallelSectContent').show();
            $( this ).find('.dropZone').empty().append( 'Droped');      
            }
                });
});
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is obvious. See, when you hover over the droppable element, you show a new element which is not inside the droppable. So, when you move to the new element i.e. parallelSectContent, you are actually moving out of the droppable part and hence the 'out' method is invoked which hides the 'parallelSectContent'. Possible solution is to place this element inside the droppable or use the default placeholder feature.

Comment: parallelSectContent is already inside droppable, and what is default placeholder feature ?

Comment: No, if you see the html parallelSectContent is inside the #droppable but not inside parallelSectHeadr. Second, your html is invalid. You are using same ID on multiple elements.

Comment: I removed duplicate id

Comment: @Jitu You removed from where..? Locally..? I can still see duplicate `id`'s in the shared fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/6jjR2/50/

This is what I am referring to.

CSS:

```
.displayNone {
    display:none;
}
.parallelSectHeadr {
    background: powderblue;
    height: auto;
}
#droppable {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.parallelSectContent {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: gray;
    padding: 10px;
}
#dragLi li {
    background: pink;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <ul id="dragLi">
                    <li>part 1</li>
                    <li>part 2</li>
                    <li>part 3</li>
                    <li>part 4</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td width="80%">
                <div class="reviewersListDv">
                    <div id="droppable">
                        <div class="parallelSectHeadr"> <span class="floatRight reviewStatusBx pending">Drop Header</span>

                            <div class="parallelSectContent clearfix displayNone">  <span class="dropZone">Drop  over here</span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="droppable">
                        <div class="parallelSectHeadr"> <span class="floatRight reviewStatusBx pending">Drop Header</span>

                            <div class="parallelSectContent clearfix displayNone">  <span class="dropZone">Drop  over here</span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="droppable">
                        <div class="parallelSectHeadr"> <span class="floatRight reviewStatusBx pending">Drop Header</span>

                            <div class="parallelSectContent clearfix displayNone">  <span class="dropZone">Drop  over here</span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I moved the 'parallelSectContent' inside the 'parallelSectHeadr'. Removed the `height` and `line-height` from CSS. This should work for you now. You can add new CSS to style it

Comment: It is almost what i want but when i move little more down then parallelSectContent disappear

Comment: @Jitu You can increase the gap between the draggable elements, and also increase the height. This will solve it. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/6jjR2/53/

Comment: Yaa I think spacing is the issue.